# Laravel parsing Input from a multiple select box not working

Tags: laravel, controller, request, multipleselection

This is my pubf in my Controller which handles the request:

```
public function addPermissionsToRoleHandler($rid, Request $request)
{
        $role = Role::find($rid);
        dd($request->permissions);
        foreach($request->permissions as $perm)
        {
            $permission = Permission::find($perm->id);
            $role->attachPermission($permission);
        }

        return redirect()->route('showSpecificRole', $rid);
}
```

This is how I defined my multiple select-box:

```
{!! Form::select('permissions[]', $permissions, null, array('class' => 'selectpicker show-tick', 'data-live-search' => 'true', 'id' => 'permission_select', 'multiple' => true)) !!}
```

Why is my `dd()` returning null? `$request->permission` is empty. `dd($request)` only has `token_`.

Comment: Show your route file and `Form::open`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WBrVDUER

Comment: According to me this happens when you submit the form without checking up the check boxes.
If you want to receive the value of the checkbox from the form, then you should select the checkbox before submitting the form.

Comment: You're right. This is a problem with bootstrap-select.js not transferring data.... without it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment so am posting as an answer. I am not sure, but I think it may be because the Request needs to be the first argument ?

Comment: Hi there, i think i got the answer, it is because you are using dd(). It won't allow the request to complete. Please try with dump() instead.

Comment: Well it tells me `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I thinks its because `permissions[]` is not transferred?

Comment: I am not familiar with laravel's form syntax so am afraid i cannot help. But I have had issues with being unable to access request variables when the request cycle is terminated with dd().